# Is it possible to include folder from parent theme for child theme to use?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a folder in my parent theme that overrides how one plugin looks. If I don't copy that folder to my child theme, the look of the child theme will be different from the parent theme.

Is it possible to somehow, in child theme's functions.php file, include that folder (make child theme use that folder). I've searched all over but didn't find anything.

The only way to make the child theme looks like the parent (that I can then modify) is to copy that folder in the child theme folder.

I tried with

```
$theme_folder = scandir(get_template_directory_uri().'/folder');
```

But I get the following warnings

```
Warning: scandir(...): failed to open dir: not implemented in \functions.php on line 20

Warning: scandir(): (errno 9): Bad file descriptor in \functions.php on line 20
```

And I've read that that may be because of lack of permissions on the server.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding how `scandir` works, but I suspect you want [`get_template_directory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory), not `get_template_directory_uri` (you want the path, not the URI)

Comment: I'll try with that (don't know why I  didn't in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Copy parent  folder in your child folder.

Comment: Ultimately that's the easy solution :D

Comment: Hello  @dingo_d Please accept the answer it will be help to other users

Comment: Well originally it's not what I needed ;) That's not very user friendly solution, especially for someone who is not an expert in wordpress. 
Since I needed that for theme development, the main concern is to make it maximally user friendly. And that means that users shouldn't need to open ftp at all...

Answer (score 0):

if it were a styling problem, Wordpress good practices said that styles should be added by enqueuing.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

You should try to confirm if your theme really do in that way and if your child theme does too.

If your theme is overriding php template files, you just copy that folder to your child theme, edit what you want and delete unedited files.

Anyway I recommend to check theme documentation or ask support. Most themes have a child theme file to download or instructions to do as theme developers likes.